# Imported data, duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, npgsql

I am migrating data from MSSQL. 
I created the database in PostgreSQL via npgsql generated migration. I moved the data across and now when the code tries to insert a value I am getting
'duplicate key value violates unique constraint'

The npgsql tries to insert a column with Id 1..how ever the table already has Id over a thousand.

Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL is 2.2.3 (latest)

In my context builder, I have

```
 modelBuilder.ForNpgsqlUseIdentityColumns();
```

In which direction should I dig to resolve such an issue?

The code runs fine if the database is empty and doesn't have any imported data

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The values inserted during the migration contained the primary key value, so the sequence behind the column wasn't incremented and is kept at 1. A normal insert - without specifying the PK value - calls the sequence, get the `1`, which already exists in the table.

To fix it, you can bump the sequence to the current max value.

```
SELECT setval(
        pg_get_serial_sequence('myschema.mytable','mycolumn'), 
        max(mycolumn)) 
FROM myschema.mytable;
```

If you already know the sequence name, you can shorten it to

```
SELECT setval('my_sequence_name', max(mycolumn)) 
FROM myschema.mytable;
```

Comment: When I am running the first command  " SELECT setval(
        pg_get_serial_sequence('public.LogEntries','Id'), 
        max(Id)) 
FROM public.LogEntries; "   I am getting relation does not exists

Comment: same for second command -   SELECT setval('LogEntries_Id_seq', max(Id)) 
FROM public.LogEntries;

Comment: I found ddl for the sequence - CREATE SEQUENCE public."LogEntries_Id_seq"..and I could see it's values via SELECT last_value, log_cnt, is_called
FROM public."LogEntries_Id_seq";

Comment: ALTER sequence public."LogEntries_Id_seq" restart with 13238;  worked, but I have 107 tables

Comment: SELECT setval('"public"."LogEntries_Id_seq"', max("LogEntries"."Id") ) FROM public."LogEntries";  Found correct syntax.....

Comment: if you add correct syntax to your examples, I will count it as the answer

Comment: @SimeonGrigorovich Ah yes, a missing quote. Note that since you use tables/columns with upper cases, you will need to add the double quotes everywhere --> it's much easier to always use lower case names