# Postgresql primary key violation duplicate key value

Tags: postgresql, unique, primary-key

Can some body tell me please why I am getting

> Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique
> constraint

if I try to make simple insert to the Postgresql table? I made some insert via csv file to the table, and now I am not able to make simple insert into the table. Why the database still use the id which is already taken?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Imported data, duplicate key value violates unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55423647/imported-data-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint)